# What is the difference between special orthogonal matrices and other general orthogonal matrices?

Tags: matrices, orthogonal-matrices

In a book that I'm currently reading it is stated that

> If $\det (R) = +1$ (where $R$ is an orthogonal matrix) then the matrix $R$ represents a pure rotation [...] If $\det(R) = -1$ then the matrix $R$ represents a pure rotation + reflection.

I am very confused by this description; I still do not know what their difference really is (is it that when $\det (R) = 1$ we are only dealing with rotations and not reflections (but aren't reflections some form of rotation?); what does the $+$ sign mean (does it mean "or" or "a reflection followed by a rotation")). 
I would appreciate it if someone would explicitly describe their differences for me.

Comment: In $2$ dimensions you could contrast rotations about the origin with reflections about a line through the origin

Comment: If you look at your right hand reflected in the mirror, it appears to be a left hand.  No amount of rotating your hand will achieve that.  Reflections reverse orientation, and rotations preserve it.  As to the other question, I guess they mean a rotation followed by a reflection, but I would just call this a reflection.

Comment: Some reflections are rotations. E.g. $-I_2$, is both a reflection about the origin and also an 180-degree rotation on $\mathbb R^2$. However, in the cited passage, I believe that the term "reflection" refers specifically to **reflection about a hyperplane**, i.e. an $R$ such that $Rv=-v$ for some nonzero vector $v$ and $Ru=u$ for every $u\perp v$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but aren't reflections some form of rotation?

The answer to this question is **no**, and I suspect that's where your confusion lies. If you take an asymmetric figure such as the figure ${\large\mathrm L}$ and rotated it, you would never be able to get it to look like its horizontal reflection (try it!). So if $\det R=1$, then $R$ corresponds to  a rotation of the plane, whereas if $\det R=-1$, then it corresponds to either just a reflection, or a reflection followed by a rotation of the plane (in the $2\mathrm{D}$ case).